# Day Exception in Events in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am currently doing a simulation model in AnyLogic of a Distribution Center where from Monday to Saturday I use an event to trigger the loading of a truck. I wish to program this loading every day at the same time, but how can I do it so it happens everyday EXCEPT Sundays. I currently have it as triggered: timeout and mode: cyclic, using calendar dates...

Comment: I already been able to fix this with a schedule, but the thing is I would want the schedule to start after a week of the model running... (In the event I was able to put the first occurrence like this). Is it possible to add this first occurrence in a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

sure, the easy way is to just add a manual exception to the schedule as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

And the more advanced way is to use a Dynamic Event that executes your daily action.

In the model start code, call `create_MyDynamicEvent(7, DAY)` to make it trigger after the first 7 days of the sim.

Then in the Dynamic Event action code, add whatever should happen every day. And also add a line that re-creates the same Dynamic event in 1 day, like

```
create_MyDynamicEvent(1, DAY)
```

This would then trigger every day, even Sunday. To avoid that, you can add an if-clause in the dynamic event action code to only execute your code if it is not Sunday.